# Local existence for $-y''(x)=x^{-3}y(x)$ with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A numerical result indicates that the initial value problem
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-y''(x) & =\frac{y(x)}{x^3} & \text{with } x>0, \\
y(0)&=1, \\
y'(0)&=0,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
has a solution at least locally. How to obtain a local existence rigorously? We often look for a fixed point of
$$
y \mapsto \int_0^x (1-\frac xt) \frac{y(t)}{t^2}dt,
$$
but it seems that we have difficulty dealing with the weight $x^{-3}$ which is singular at $x=0$.

Comment: What numerical result and how did you verify that it relevant for the exact solution?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I used Maple with initial data near 0, not at 0, since the equation is singular. So I thought that the above IVP should have a solution, at least a local one; but it seems that this is not true according to the comment made by Goncalo.

Comment: Compare the solutions when you set the initial conditions at times $t_0=10^{-k}$ for several $k$. It might help to use a logarithmic scale for the time axis. In a "nice" case these solutions will visibly converge.